# How to run scp command without password from ubuntu to centOS machine

Tags: 14.04, scp

I want to run scp command from my machine(Ubuntu_14) to my server (CentOS_6)

I have already generate a pair of authentication keys,
also append my public key to my servers .ssh/authorized_keys,
now I can run ssh command from my machine to my server without password, but when I am going to run scp command it asking for password

Please help me..

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you use SSH without a password as opposed to SCP (resulting in a password question) so we can see if you're using the commands correctly or if you're doing anything odd? Does the password question come from the SSH server or from the local SSH (key chain) agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can ssh to the server only with your key, you can scp with the key too - just make sure to point it with `scp -i /path/to/private_key <source> <target>`.

You can also use an `ssh-agent` program - you won't have to use the `-i keyfile` switch everytime (this applies for ssh too). Start it with:

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add -L #this lists the keys you have added (the public key)
ssh-add /path/to/private_key #this will add a key
```

Comment: Its working with -i keyfile file, but I don't want to use keyfile each time. I tried ssh-agent, but it asks for password.
Please help..

Comment: ok, I assume you have added your private key with `ssh-add <privatekey>`, what happens when you type `ssh-add -L` - do you see your public key?

Comment: yes, I am able to see public key but it asks for password

Comment: what user are you doing this with, and does the server has the same user with that public key in authorized_keys file (do you connect with just `ssh -i key myuser@server`)? If you connect with a different user it will prompt for a password.

Comment: Users are different, on my machine its bitnami user with root privilages and on server its root

Comment: so your public key is in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote site. You already have your key in your ssh-agent, so now just try `ssh root@<server>` and it should work.

Comment: It's odd that `scp` needs an explicit specification of the private key file to use while `ssh` doesn't. According to the manual of `scp` the `-i` option is passed directly to the `ssh` command invoked by `scp` in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up `ssh-keygen` as explained [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216499537-How-to-configure-passwordless-login-in-Mac-OS-X-and-Linux), you can do

`scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /local/path/to/file remote@ip.com:/path/in/remote/server/`

where `id_rsa` is the local key generated in the `ssh-keygen` setup.

If you want to lessen typing each time, you can modify your `.bash_profile` file and put

```
alias remote_scp='scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /local/path/to/file remote@ip.com:/path/in/remote/server/
```

Then from your terminal do `source ~/.bash_profile`. Afterwards if you type `remote_scp` in your terminal it should run the `scp` command without password.